# rotate imageview by only using (touching) their corners swift 3 or 4

Tags: animation, swift3, imageview

Hi I would like to implement an rotating imageview where user can rotate the imageview by touching only the corners.

how could i implement that. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to implement an rotating imageview where user can rotate the imageview by touching only the corners.

There are two parts to this task, and I'm not sure which one you're asking about:

1. How to do something in response to a dragging gesture.
2. How to rotate a view.

Whether you're talking about iOS or macOS, there are at least two options for responding to a dragging operation. One is to track the touch or mouse event yourself. Touches and mouse interactions both have a beginning, when the finger touches the screen or the mouse button is depressed; a middle, when the location of the finger or cursor may change; and an end, when the finger leaves the screen or the mouse button is released. Both operating systems have events for these things that are sent through their respective event handling systems.

An easier method is to use a gesture recognizer, which is usually easier to get right AND the existing gesture recognizers encourage you to implement the expected behavior by making that the easiest option. For example, UIKit and AppKit each have a rotation gesture recognizer that recognizes two touches moving in opposite directions as a rotation gesture, since that's a common way to rotate objects. But you can also implement your own gesture recognizer that can notice that a touch happens a) for longer than some minimum time, b) within some minimum distance from a corner, and c) with movement in a direction that would cause rotation. So, if you want to handle dragging in order to rotate something, look into gesture recognizers.

UIView and NSView both provide methods for rotating a view in its superview's coordinate system. NSView provides a `frameRotation` property that you can set, and UIView has a `transform` property to which you can apply Core Graphics functions like `CGAffineTransformRotate()`.

In summary, what you should do is to create a gesture recognizer subclass that recognizes the rotation gesture that you want and rotates the view that it's attached to. Then instantiate that gesture recognizer and apply it to the view that you want to rotate.

Comment: Thanks @Caleb for you answer. I know how to rotate a view by using "rotate gesture" or "CGAffineTransformRotate()". But the rotation works when it touch in the whole view. But i want to rotate the view by touching only in the four corners of the view. What could be the logic to do that ?